# Merge close centroids

Tags: matlab

suppose I want to cluster data with 3 features. After running a clustering algorithm as a result I got the following 6 cluster centers:

`246.844727524039    250.149069392025    94.0942587475951
121.988259016632    162.247917376091    100.033277638728
246.832071340390    250.114555535282    94.0640197467370
247.069762690783    237.380529249185    176.069941183101
57.6643682370364    59.8647220036974    44.0150398556124
253.248727658092    254.655572229735    71.2948414962619`

Anyone can notice that centers 1 and 3 are very close to each other. Is there a way to merge them as one center? I'm looking something like a function that returns the merged cluster centers. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest the following approach:

1. define a threshold which represents the minimal possible Eucledean distance between two centroids.
2. iterate over all the possible pairs, and if some their distance is lower then the thresohld - unite them.

You can perform this calculation as follows:

```
[m,n] = size(centers); 
threshold = 1; %defines a threshold
centroidsToMerge = [];
for i=1:m
    for j=(i+1):m
        if norm(centers(i,:)-centers(j,:))<threshold
            centroidsToMerge = [centroidsToMerge;[i,j]];
        end
    end
end
```

results for threshold=1:

```
centroidsToMerge = [1, 3]
```

results for threshold=30:

```
centroidsToMerge = [ 1,3 ; 1,6 ; 3,6 ]
```

If you have the Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox you can use MATLAB's [pdist](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist.html) function in order to calculate all the pair distanced automatically, and thus maybe avoiding the for loops. Unfortunately, I don't have this toolbox at the moment so I wasn't able to use it. However, I still believe that it is a good way to start with.